# Algorithm used by pluploadQueue to "randomize" names

Tags: random, filenames, plupload

Does anybody know, what algorithm Plupload widget uses, when [`pluploadQueue.rename`](http://www.plupload.com/docs/pluploadQueue) = `TRUE`?

I've sent 77 test files and **all of them** have file name starting with `o_18pm0noe` (first ten characters equal). Only rest of the file name differs.

I wonder, why such pattern is used and can we somehow control it to have *entire file name* randmized (in any "natural" way, that is -- not by changing Plupload source code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anybody know, what algorithm Plupload widget uses, when pluploadQueue.rename = TRUE?

According to [the sources](https://github.com/moxiecode/moxie/blob/master/src/javascript/core/utils/Basic.js#L302), it is a combination of current time and some random numbers (both base32).

> Can we somehow control it to have entire file name randmized (in any "natural" way, that is -- not by changing Plupload source code)?

Maybe you can try to set the file name to a custom randomized name? See [`_enableRenaming`](https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/blob/master/js/jquery.ui.plupload/jquery.ui.plupload.js#L1249) for an example of file renaming (`file.name = nameInput.val() + ext;`).